# Python 3, Converting a string storing binary data to Int

Tags: python, string, binary

I have the variable Number which is equal to "0b11001010" and I want it to be the type int like a normal binary is stored e.g.   0b11001010

```
Number = "0b11001010"
NewNumber = 0b11001010
```

is there a really simple way and I am overlooking it?

Thanks.

Comment: `0b11001010` is just *syntactic sugar*, a different way to spell an integer number. Both `0b11001010` and `202` mean the same thing, an integer value of 202.

Comment: You can *print* the value of `NewNumber` as binary, but it won't be *stored* using that notation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In python you can only create it as a binary value (as a syntactic sugar), it will be converted into an integer immediately. Try it for yourself:

```
>>> 0b11001010
202
```

The same thing will happen with octal and hexadecimal values. So you can convert your binary string to an integer, with the `int()` function's `base` argument like:

```
>>> int('0b11001010', 2)
202
```

After the conversion you can do any operations on it -- just like with an integer, since it is an integer.

Of course you can convert it back at any time to a binary string, with the builtin `bin()` function:

```
>>> bin(202)
0b11001010
```

Comment: The output is still a string.. You could just `print(Number)` and be done with it.

Comment: If I do, type(bin(int(Number, 2))) it comes up as string, and the function I send this number off to can only accept an int in binary form :/. I can send a little code if you want.

Comment: @JamesClarke please send!

Comment: So the function is along the lines of Send(Code, Addr, Data) The Data value is the Binary in question, Addr is a hex location of the Microchip on a board connected on a raspberry Pi, This info then gets sent to the function SendValue()  where it toggles a clk and then sends the info and toggles it back. The Data can be Binary or Hex. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: @JamesClarke please try it with the converted int value, and let's see what happens. What is the error if any?

Comment: Thanks it worked. Didn't seem to work with the int value before :). Thanks a lot.